# mysql sort output by alphabet but get ASC?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql statement:

```
SELECT userid,username FROM table1 ORDER BY userid DESC LIMIT 15
```

What I want to do is get the last 15 from the table, but then also sort the username in alphabetical order for output.

What is the syntax to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html) like this :-

```
select userid, username
from 
(
  SELECT userid,username FROM table1 ORDER BY userid DESC LIMIT 15
) as last_15
order by username;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

> SELECT username, userid FROM table1 WHERE userid IN (SELECT userid
>   FROM table1 ORDER BY userid DESC LIMIT 15) ORDER BY username ASC

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap your original SELECT in a new one

```
SELECT userid,username FROM (
    SELECT userid,username FROM table1 ORDER BY userid DESC LIMIT 15
) ORDER BY username ASC
```

Or as the data is very simple you could load the original results into an array in PHP and sort the array.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one

```
SELECT userid,username FROM table1 ORDER BY username ASC LIMIT 15,0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  last_15.userid,  last_15.username
from 
(
  SELECT userid,username FROM table1 ORDER BY userid DESC LIMIT 15
) as last_15
order by last_15.username;
```

This query will run even fast